# How to nest a function that responds to outside of function call?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

I'm trying to figure out how I can solve this issue. I have a Raspberry Pi that is set up with a breadboard that consists of:

- 1 RGB light
- 2 buttons (left and right)
- 1 OLED screen

Each component works and I can run each one. What I'm trying to do is write a script that will allow me to select the **"mode"** with the left button (everything off vs lights vs screen on).

When a mode is selected, the right button then allows me to select between options within that mode. Below is the code as I have it:

```py
def off():
    lights = [red,green,blue]
    for light in lights:
        light.off()
        
def lightSelector():
    off()
    number = 0
    while number < 5:
        if rightButton.is_pressed:
            if number == 0:
                off()
                red.on()
                sleep(1)
                number += 1
            elif number == 1:
                off()
                green.on()
                sleep(1)
                number += 1
            elif number == 2:
                off()
                blue.on()
                sleep(1)
                number += 1
            elif number == 3:
                off()
                row()
                sleep(1)
                number+= 1
            else:
                number = 0
                
def picture():
    image = Image.open('grant.jpeg')
    image_r = image.resize((width,height), Image.BICUBIC)
    image_bw = image_r.convert("1")

    for x in range(width):
            for y in range(height):
                    oled.pixel(x,y,bool(int(image_bw.getpixel((x,y)))))
    oled.show()
 
def oledOff():
    oled.fill(0)
    oled.show()

def buttons():
    x = 0
    y = 0
    while y is 0:
        print('x = ' , x)
        print('y = ' , y)
        if leftButton.is_pressed:
            if x == 0 :
                oledOff()
                off()
                sleep(0.5)
                x += 1
            elif x == 1:
                oledOff()
                off()
                lightSelector()
                sleep(0.5)
                x += 1
            elif x == 2:
                oledOff()
                off()
                picture()
                sleep(0.5)
                x += 1
            else:
                x = 0

oledOff()
off()
buttons()
```

The idea is that the `buttons()` function is the main overall function and will call the others as needed. My issue is that once I get to `y == 1`, or the `lightSelector()` function, it no longer registers that the leftButton is being pressed and won't switch to the next mode and I'm stuck in the `lightSelector()` function.

I know at baseline I can spell out `lightSelector` within the buttons function instead of calling another function but I'm trying to not be as verbose. I don't have any experience with threading or multprocessing and looked into it but couldn't see how that would help.

Comment: Kepp a button state for your light - do not loop inside lightSelector. when entering lightSelector check wich state your light is at, advance it and return to main function. main loop around the "get if button is pressed"

Comment: `while y is 0:` is a code smell - use `while y == 0:` or in your case use `while True` and get rid of `y` as it never changes if you need to escape the endless loop use `break`

Comment: your shown code is no [mre] - there is no way "to get y == 1" - there is a whole function pictures that is completely unrelated. You have a program logic problem, you already identified what is wrong (being stuck in certain parts) - so change your program flow logic to fix it.... hardly something we are able to help.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I changed some of this, thanks for the input. I was able to get a solution by an "if rightButton.is_pressed: do light things; elif leftButton.is_pressed: return" in the lightSelector function. This isn't quite what I was looking for, I was thinking of some process where the main function continues to run in the background and the nested function would respond but this seems outside of my skill level.

Comment: @brokestudent for the latter [just use async](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) if you want, it basically hides that `while True` for you and you can then play just with "events" directly.

Comment: @brokestudent for the latter [just use async](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) if you want, it basically hides that while True for you and you can then play just with "events" directly. [Also relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45615121/5994041) to async if you start thinking about one "thread" being a slave for task processing e.g. handling hw inputs and other "thread" being just the GUI/CLI view.